# How to workaround lack of success callback in ZRSSfeed?

Tags: jquery, rss, event-handling

I have a feed page that needs to have a click handler applied to every link in the rss feed..

I'm using ZRSSfeed which is great but it won't do callbacks so the .click() function runs long before the rss content arrives

there's a fiddle of this here:

http://jsfiddle.net/PMtCN/

thanks much

Comment: interesting side note there is evidently a patch to add callback to Zrssfeed on jquery site

http://plugins.jquery.com/node/14919

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding the issue, you want to attach a click handler to the result, but don't know when the content is loaded.  If this is the case, then simply use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> Description: Attach a handler to the
>   event for all elements which match the
>   current selector, now and in the
>   future.

http://jsfiddle.net/PMtCN/11/

```
 jQuery('#linkwidget a').live("click",function(){ 
    alert('Hello World');
    return false; 
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest version has a callback function, so you can now perform actions on feed items after it has loaded.

The example below limits the feed title length to 14 characters:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').rssfeed('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews',{},function(e) {

        $('h4 a',e).each(function(i) {

            var title = $(this).text();
            if (title.length > 14) $(this).text(title.substring(0,14)+'...');
        });
    });
});
```

http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the callback, and you want to individually apply the click function to each match node you can use code like this,

```
var COM_MYSITE_RSS_CHECK;
var COM_MYSITE_RSS_CHECK_COUNT = 0;
var COM_MYSITE_RSS_CHECK_FREQ = 100;
var COM_MYSITE_RSS_CHECK_MAX = 100;
function wait_for_rss(){
    if (jQuery('#linkwidget a').length > 0 || COM_MYSITE_RSS_CHECK_COUNT > COM_MYSITE_RSS_CHECK_MAX  )
    {

        clearInterval(COM_MYSITE_RSS_CHECK);
         jQuery('#linkwidget a').click(function(){ 
            alert('Hello World');
            return false; 
          }); 

    }
    COM_MYSITE_RSS_CHECK_COUNT++;
}
```

and then after you call the ajax request,

```
COM_MYSITE_RSS_CHECK = setInterval(wait_for_rss, COM_MYSITE_RSS_CHECK_FREQ);
```

Or if individually binding to the elements is not required, you could look into the [jQuery Live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method of binding functions, which does not require the elements to have already been created prior to binding.

Comment: this is a very nice brute force approach that will come in handy somewhere it not here  !  .. thanks much